# OHV VPS ports not modified. Where are those rule set?

Tags: debian, firewall, port, ovh, debian-10

I have a problem with a VPS ports config (on ovh.com).

- I set up Debian 10 and updated it.
- I didn't install any firewall software.
- [OVH infrastructure is protected by a global firewall](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/firewall-network/), but on my panel it's shown as disabled and there are no rules applied.
- Default ports work fine (HTTP, TCP, UDP, SSH, FTP, DNS and SSL).

**EXAMPLE (FTP)**

FTP works just fine on port 21:

**client**

```
$ ftp XX.XX.XX.XX
Connected to XX.XX.XX.XX.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Name (XX.XX.XX.XX:f): NAME
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

If I go to [yougetsignal.com](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and it shows **Port 21 is open** and **Port 2121 is closed**.

Then I change the listening port to 2121, and it doesn't connect any more

**server**

```
# sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
# changes done: "listening_port=2121"
# sudo service vsftpd restart

$ sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :2121
tcp6   0   0   :::2121   :::*   LISTEN   28582/vsftpd

#rules allow all in
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

$ sudo ip6tables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

**client**

```
$ ftp
ftp> open XX.XX.XX.XX
ftp: connect: Connection refused
ftp> open XX.XX.XX.XX:2121
ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

If I go to [yougetsignal.com](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and it shows **Port 21 is closed** and **Port 2121 is closed**.

Same happens for any other port.

**Where else can be those rules be defined, since any change I make on ip6tables or iptables seems to do nothing?**

**UPDATE**

As commented by Michael, it was space, not colon.

**client**

```
ftp> open XX.XX.XX.XX 2121
Connected to 51.222.30.108.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
```

On the other hand, the external test still throw "Closed", and the command commented by vidarlo, `netcat -lp 2121`, returns `Can't grab 0.0.0.0:2121 with bind`.

Comment: There should be a space between the host and port, not  a colon. See the man page.

Comment: In addition, it's often easier to fault find using `netcat`. Fire up `netcat -lp 2121` and it will dutifully listen on port 2121 on all interfaces. This removes complex software from the mix, and allows you to trivially establish if the problem is in the network layer or your configuration.

Comment: I updated the question, @vidarlo . Does that mean there is an error?

Comment: @Fahed It means the port is *probably* in use. `netstat -tlnp | grep 2121` should show you.